# Persisting data in an axis object

Tags: web-services, tomcat, soap, axis

Forgive me if this is a dumb question, I unfortunately have an assignment due! I am running apache axis under tomcat and need to deploy a simple web service class, see below.

I installed the counter file below as "MyCounter.jws" in the /tomcat/webapps/axis/ folder. Tomcat finds it and makes a corresponding MyCounter.xml. I use WSDL2Java on the XML file and client calls seem to work, but internal state is not saved:

Every time I call MyCounter.call from the client side, the return value is always 1. It seems the constructor is always called before the method call. How can I make it so the mycounter integer persists across requests?

```
public class MyCounter
{
    int mycounter;

    public MyCounter()
    {
        mycounter = 0;
    }

    public int call()
    {
        mycounter++;
        return mycounter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think persisting is maybe the wrong word, I think what you mean is that the Java Class is not instantiated every time you call the service.

See: https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#Scoped_Services

So you would need to change the Service definition yo achieve this.

I don't think that with the JWS files you will be able to configure the session scope. As the docs say:
https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#JWS_Java_Web_Service_Files_-_Instant_Deployment

Quote:

> Important: JWS web services are intended for simple web services. You
>   cannot use packages in the pages, and as the code is compiled at run
>   time you can not find out about errors until after deployment.
>   Production quality web services should use Java classes with custom
>   deployment.

So if you want to use such features you should consider using some of the other ways Axis offers to setup a WebService.
Also I would strongly recommend using Axis2 instead of Axis1:
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/

Axis1 can be quite complicated with the WSDD files to setup. Apart from Axis1 no more actively developed/maintained.